# How to log connect/disconnects of outgoing ssh sessions?

Tags: ssh, logs, audit

I'm looking to log connections/disconnections from outgoing ssh sessions. Is this something auditd can do? I am able to get logs via auditbeat of the connections going outbound but the tricky part is tracking when the session is disconnected..

I have even tried using ss and parsing that every 1 second via filebeat, as ss has a field for connection status, but the status only ever shows established.

Example output of what I would be looking for would be:

TIMESTAMP 192.168.1.200:22 CONNECTED

TIMESTAMP 192.168.1.200:22 DISCONNECTED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working after some research. Here is for anyone else wanting to know how to do it:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "Connection established: "
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --tcp-flags FIN FIN -j LOG --log-prefix "Connection closed: "
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --tcp-flags RST RST -j LOG --log-prefix "Connection closed: "
```

Comment: If you are a firewall admin which do this for security reasons keep in mind this only works as long as the remote ssh server listens on port 22. If you need to protocol it for legal reasons you could add a ssh proxy inside your local network which monitors all connection and then block all other unneeded ports.